# Android TextView Marquee joggling

Tags: android, textview, marquee

I have the following Android Layout for a scrolling text:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_static_marquee"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:shadowColor="#0f0f0f"
        android:shadowDx="1.5"
        android:shadowDy="1.3"
        android:shadowRadius="1.6"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:marqueeRepeatLimit="-1"
        android:scrollHorizontally="true"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:textColor="#ffeeeeee"
        android:text="" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

the scroll text is joggling (some letters are jumping right and left). With certain fonts it works, but most fonts are joggling. Any recommendation?

Tried with several different fonts.